# php Rotating image and resaving

Tags: php, image, rotation

So I have an image uploaded what I'm trying to do is have the user rotate it, receive that value and rotate the image and replace the original with the new image.

So I have a button:

```
<a href="#" data-id="2" class="btn btn-primary">Rotate</a>
```

In my js file:

```
$('.rotate').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   if(rotate < 360)
    rotate = rotate +90;
   else
    rotate = 0;

   var id = $(this).data('id');

   $('.img-container img').attr('style', '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)');

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "functions/post",
       data: { rotate: rotate, id: id }
   });
```

});

and inside "functions/post":

```
$degrees = $_POST['rotate'];
$postid = $_POST['postid'];

//user the postid to get the imagefilepath from db
$filename = '../img/uploads/' . $post->getimagepath();

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

// Output
imagejpeg($rotate);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($rotate);
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($newImage, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, imagesx($source), imagesy($source));
imagejpeg($newImage, realpath('../img/uploads/' . $post->getimagepath()));
// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
imagedestroy($newImage);
```

but it doesn't save the rotated file.. :(
this code i got it from searching through so and google but can't seem to make it work for me yet.  None of this code is set in stone so anything that needs changing aslong as it makes it work then its all good and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked `$post->getimagepath()`?

Comment: Also, why are you setting the header to `image/jpeg`?

Comment: yes the $post->getimagepath returns the filename and the header idk I thought I had to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving the rotated image, you're saving the original image over again.

Try this:

```
$degrees = $_POST['rotate'];
$postid = $_POST['postid'];

//user the postid to get the imagefilepath from db
$filename = '../img/uploads/' . $post->getimagepath();

// Content type
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

// Load
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Rotate
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $degrees, 0);

imagejpeg($rotate, realpath('../img/uploads/' . $post->getimagepath()));
// Free the memory
imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);
```

(not tested) but you get the idea.

Comment: yea I just saw that too, but for some reason it still didn't save it.

Comment: Like I said, it's untested. Play around with it ;) You're probably close.

Comment: it worked but i had to use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] otherwise it wasn't finding it.  Thanks!